# Matrix Orthogonality

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the eigenvector matrix like this

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \frac{-b + \sqrt{(b^{2} + 8a^2)}}{2a} & -\frac{b + \sqrt{(b^2 + 8a^2)}}{2a} \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Are they orthogonal?

If not, should I use the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?

Comment: A simple computation should lead you to the fact that the columns are orthogonal but not with unit length.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh how can I have unit length?

Comment: If you know Gram-Schmidt, you should know what it means for two vectors to be orthogonal with respect to a scalar product, and how to verify it. What is more specifically your confusion?

Comment: @user438666 I normalized them in order to prove diagonalization of the matrix, but it failed. That's why now I'm not sure anymore what I did was right.

Comment: as @AniruddhaDeshmukh says just take the scalar product between the vectors and notice they are $0$, but also notice that for example your first vector has length $\sqrt{2}$, just divide by this number to get a vector that is of length $1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & \frac{-b + \sqrt{(b^{2} + 8a^2)}}{2a} & \frac{-b - \sqrt{(b^2 + 8a^2)}}{2a} \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$  is orthogonal if, and only if, its column vectors 
$$
v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad 
v_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
 1  \\
 \frac{-b + \sqrt{(b^{2} + 8a^2)}}{2a} \\
 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
v_3= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
\frac{-b -\sqrt{(b^2 + 8a^2)}}{2a} \\
 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
are orthogonal  vectors. It is easy to verify that 
$$
\langle v_1, v_2\rangle =0 \quad \mbox{ and } \quad \langle v_1, v_3\rangle =0 .
$$
A bit more laborious, but not difficult, is to calculate $v_2\cdot v_3$. In fact, 
$$
v_2\cdot v_3
=
1\cdot 1+
\left( \frac{-b + \sqrt{(b^{2} + 8a^2)}}{2a} \right)\cdot 
\left( \frac{-b - \sqrt{(b^{2} + 8a^2)}}{2a} \right)
+
1\cdot 1
\\
=
1+
\frac{b^2 - (b^{2} + 8a^2)}{4a^2} 
+
1
\\
=
2+
\frac{- 8a^2}{4a^2} 
\\
=0
$$

Comment: May I ask a further question?

Comment: If it is a question with respect to the answer given, I think so. Which would be?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193586/normalization

Comment: I think you should ask this new question as a question on math.stackexchange.com